# Loop styling in React Native stylesheet

Tags: react-native

i wanna ask about this idea, loop arrays then combine them into 1 styling sheet on react native. I'm using react-native on expo development.

the issue:

```
const Spacing = StyleSheet.create({
  marginTop5: {
    marginTop: 5
  },
  marginTop10: {
    marginTop: 10
  }, 
  marginTop15: {
    marginTop: 15
  },  
  marginTop20: {
    marginTop: 20
  },....
})
```

we can see a repetitive code being written again & again so many time.
so i think i need to write it this way:

```
const spacing = ['margin', 'padding'];
const direction = ['Top', 'Bottom', 'Left', 'Right'];
const amounts = [ -100, -75, -50, -40, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100 ];
const amountsPositive = [ 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100 ];

// Spacing template
_spacingMap = (space, direct, amount) => {
  return space+direct+amount+' { '+space+direct+': '+amount+' }';
}
const testThis = _spacingMap();

const spacingLoop = spacing.map((space) => {
  direction.map((direct) => {
    amountsPositive.map((amount) => {

      _spacingMap(space, direct, amount);

    });
  });
});
```

so it will print out the same thing as the spacing list on above, without so many code to type. But 1 problem, i dont know how to make it produce the code inside "const Spacing = StyleSheet.create({ ... });" (react native stylesheet).

may i know how can i make it work inside the stylesheet? is it even possible?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at the API of [StyleSheet.create](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#create) method, it takes an object. So, all you need is to generate the object and pass the same into `StyleSheet.create` method. Consider the following code snippets

First, from `_spacingMap` return an object like

```
_spacingMap = (space, direct, amount) => {
  return {[`${space}${direct}${amount}`]: { [`${space}${direct}`]: amount }};
}
```

Then, iterate over all the arrays and generate the required object like

Using `forEach`

```
const dynamicStyle = {};
spacing.forEach(space => {
  direction.forEach(direction => {
    amountsPositive.forEach(amount => {
      Object.assign(dynamicStyle, _spacingMap(space, direction, amount));
    });
  })
});
```

Now, the `dynamicStyle` object has all the required properties, all we need is to pass this object into `StyleSheet.create` method

```
const Spacing = StyleSheet.create(dynamicStyle);
```

`Spacing` will have all the required styles as per your need. You can use `Spacing.marginTop100`.

**Note**: I have tested the above code on iOS simulator but not in `Expo` but I believe this will work on `Expo` as well.

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks @Prasun, but i get this error when trying to inject it inside stylesheet: "marginTop0" is not a valid style property. it appear that it print out "marginTop0": {"marginTop":0};is there a way to remove the double quote? cause i feel this is where the error comes from.

Comment: @KadirJailani, I tried `marginTop0` and it worked as expected but I am not on Expo though. BTW when did u get this error, when u call `ShtleSheet.create(dynamicStyle)` or when you call `Spacing.marginTop0`?

Comment: oh, it works, i done it wrong like this `StyleSheet.create({ dynamicStyle });`. it should be without the the mustache for it to works. thank you so much @Prasun

Comment: hey, where & how would you invoke this @Prasun?